# Subject-verb agreement with prepositional phrase antecedent and pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns, verb-agreement

> One of the engineers who **design** those programs is visiting with us today?

or

> One of the engineers who **designs** those programs is visiting with us today?

Comment: One of those program design engineers is visiting us today. Visit with someone sounds like southern or regional AE.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> One of the engineers designing those programs is visiting us today.

If you must include *who*, it should be:

> *One of the engineers who **designs** those programs is visiting us today.*

The subject is singular, therefore, the verb should agree with *one*.

NOTE: I deleted the *with* because the engineers are not going somewhere with you, they are visiting you.  If they are going someplace with you, you should say where you guys are visiting:

> ... *visiting [insert person/place to be visited] with us*.

Comment: On the matter of the *with* - in Britain we never *visit with* people. *Visit* is always a transitive verb - *we visit the relatives*; we do not *visit with* them. Are you British too? Or are you saying that in America, *visit* can be used transitively, as well as intransitively. For in the UK if we *visit with* someone, it means we take them somewhere e.g. *I am going to visit my aunt, with my brother*.

Comment: @WS2 I'm American and I agree with you.  I thought the the OP meant the _one of the engineers_ is visiting his company, so I deleted the _with_.

Comment: No. See Sash's answer.

Comment: @WS2 - In parts of the US we do "visit with" others.  The expression is synonymous with "converse."  It's probably euphemistic in origin.  So much for the illusion of a common language!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the meaning!

(a)"One of the engineers who design those programs is visiting us today."

The relative clause specifies which group of 'the engineers' is referred to, here: the ones that "design those programs".

(b) "One of the engineers, who designs those programs, is visiting us today."

The relative clause gives additional information about 'one of the engineers'.
You could then say: One of the engineers, who BY THE WAY designs those programs (...). The commas are obligatory!